# When can limits to both infinities exists and differ?

Tags: calculus, limits

What property of a function required to make: 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=M \neq \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=N$$

Such as: $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{3x-5}$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$
But$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

Comment: This cannot happen if $f(x)$ is a rational function (that is, it is $P(x)/Q(x)$ where $P$ and $Q$ are both polynomials). If it is not a rational function, all bets are off.

Comment: You have a very restrictive view of functions as things defined by formulas.  Functions are much more general than that.  You need to define what set of formulas you are considering, then we can try to pick out the ones that go to different limits at the two infinities.

Comment: @ZezoYasor Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special in this condition, for example for all functions in the form with $a,c \neq 0$

$$f(x)=\frac{a|x|+b}{cx+d}$$

we have that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \frac{a}{c}\quad \neq \quad \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = -\frac{a}{c}$$

and we can construct many of these examples.

Comment: Could that be generalized in a property in the function?

Comment: Maybe but it will not be useful.

Comment: @ZezoYasor there is nothing special to this, of course we can exclude for example that $f(x)$ is an even function on R but not much more than that.

Comment: @ZezoYasor for example also $1+\arctan x$ has the property but that function has nothing to do with $\frac{a|x|+b}{cx+d}$.